# CF11 Application.cfc with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, coldfusion-11

I am using ColdFusion as my backend for an AngularJS application.  I need my Application.cfc to run in order for my authentication module to run. However, because I do not have any .cfm files, it does not run on request.  The files in the root of my folder are all of the application folders (controllers/, styles/, views/, etc.).  Also at the root is my index.html which kicks off the angular application as well as Application.cfc.  I want Application.cfc to run as soon as the application is accessed.  Is there any way to do this, or will I need to make an API call to Application.cfc from a controller/service to kick it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install ColdFusion as a back-end application server, you configure your web server (Apache, IIS, etc...) to detect that a ColdFusion resource is requested (by looking at the extension of the file requested, such as .cfm) and pass the request to the ColdFusion engine. That is when Application.cfc runs. Your web server does not call ColdFusion engine for .html pages.

When you make the request to `views/` or `controllers/`, etc.., you're still calling to a 'Default Document' which is configured via your web server settings. If that 'default document' is not a ColdFusion document your Application.cfc will not run.

So, in conclusion if you want Application.cfc to run, make sure to request to a ColdFusion configured resource such as .cfm or a method on a .cfc resource.